# Codeigniter include

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use codeigniter 4 to develop a new project.
[codeigniter4-auth-master](https://github.com/divpusher/codeigniter4-auth) is one of the options to be the login module.

But I find a problem to include third party program into the project
by using codeigniter autoload.

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE   => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'App'           => APPPATH,
    'Config'        => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Auth'          => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/Auth/',
];


<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Login extends BaseController 
{
    private $image;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Code
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $logCon = new ThridParty\Auth\LoginController;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

Does anyone have an experience on this case?

error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nObT.png)

Comment: `I find a problem`...Ok. Would you like to tell us what specifically the problem is, or do we get points for guessing? Is there an error message? Or some other unexpected behaviour? Please tell us what you already know.

Comment: Sure,
Error
Class 'App\Controllers\ThridParty\Auth\LoginController' not found
I think i am miss understand some of the logic on the codeigniter framework 

The main point is, I want to call a third party login module to handle login process
the login module is placed inside the thirdparty directory.
The problem is how can I to use the thirdparth controller call from browser.

Many thanks

Comment: If you have important info like that, please use the "edit" button under your question to update the post, and show the full error message. Don't bury that info hidden in the comments :-)

Comment: thx for reply
the error message is updated on the question
Many thanks

Comment: `ThridParty` != `ThirdParty`. Please try to double-check your work.